# Validate user type - C#

Tags: c#

The first if works for me to check the username and password but the second gives me an error when entering with the type 1 user.

> if (dt2.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "2") //Error

*DB UsrType int*

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 0.'

```
    Con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from UserTbl where UsrNom='"+UnameTb.Text+"' and UsrPass='"+PassTb.Text+"'",Con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    sda.Fill(dt);

    //Error?
    SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select UsrType from UserTbl where UsrNom='" + UnameTb.Text + "' and UsrType='" + 2 + "'", Con);
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    sda2.Fill(dt2);

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        { 
            if (dt2.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "2") //Error
            {
                User = UnameTb.Text;
                Admin Obj2 = new Admin();
                Obj2.Show();
                this.Hide();
                Con.Close();

            }
            else 
            { 
                User = UnameTb.Text;
                Panel Obj = new Panel();
                Obj.Show();
                this.Hide();
                Con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error is fairly clear… `dt2` … has no rows.

Comment: Please don’t do this - use parameters - `and UsrPass='"+PassTb.Text+"'"`

Comment: This will get hacked to an sql injection attack please use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

its clear that this query

```
  SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select UsrType from UserTbl where UsrNom='" + UnameTb.Text + "' and UsrType='" + 2 + "'", Con);
```

returned 0 rows. You need to check that case

and other have said, do not do that, you are open to a sql injection attack. Use a paramterized query